# Remove existing feature from the installed WIX setup

Tags: wix, upgrade, windows-installer, wix3.8

I have a Wix Setup of my .Net appplication.I have installed it on my system.
I want to create a WIX setup with UpgradeVesion to remove some feaures from the installed setup and add new features.
i use the below code:-

```
  <Product Id="*"
   Name="MyProduct"
   Language="10313"
   Version="3.0.0.0"
   Manufacturer="My_Company"
   UpgradeCode="6ba277d97-41de-4371-a236-b757b7840f7b">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

<Upgrade Id="6ba28d97-49de-4371-a236-b757b7840f7b">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  OnlyDetect="no"
                  Maximum="3.0.0.0"
                  IncludeMaximum="yes"
                  Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" RemoveFeatures="[ProductFeature1]"/>
</Upgrade>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<MediaTemplate />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TestApp" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />

    </Feature>
<Feature Id="ProductFeature1" Title="TestApp" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponent1"/>
</Feature>
</Product>
```

But i am unable to remove the ProductFeature1.

How can i remove an existing feature from the installed setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Major upgrade for wix to achieve the same..
follow the below link:-
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx)